# Trouble with update nuget Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql from version 0.5 to version 1.33

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

We use nuget [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/0.50.0-prerelease) (**version 0.5**) in our project.

But I have updated the **version 0.5** to **version 1.33** (last version on the current time).

And I have a troubles with some models and methods:

1. Class `RecommendedAction` from namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models` is missing
2. Interface `IElasticPoolRecommendedActionsOperations` is missing
3. Interface `IElasticPoolAdvisorsOperations` is missing

It seems the missed classes are renamed or moved to other nuget package.

Where I can find missing classes?

Comment: Read Package Reference Tab on following page : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/1.33.0-preview

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, but I do not see any helpful information on Package Reference Tab.  Could you explain what do you mean more details?

Comment: For projects that support PackageReference, copy this XML node into the project file to reference the package : Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql -Version 1.33.0-preview  Read the other tabs and notes below the tab window.

Comment: @AlexanderI. From the latest API document [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models?view=azure-dotnet), `RecommendedAction`, `IElasticPoolRecommendedActionsOperations`, `IElasticPoolAdvisorsOperations` are not exist.

Comment: @LeonYue Thanks. It seems the classes were renamed or moved to other nuget. Is there any way to find this classes? Maybe exists analogs for these classes and I can rewrite code to reproduce previous behavior. But where I can find any documentation about it? I have reviewed all package, but I can't find analogs.

Comment: @AlexanderI. I also think so. I didn't find anything about this. But from the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql?view=azure-dotnet) , maybe we can find some similar inteface, such as `IElasticPoolActivitiesOperations ` or `IElasticPoolOperations `. It looks like that you need to change your code and  fount the new renamed class or interface by yourself. Can I post this as the answer?

Comment: @LeonYue Yes, you can post answer, I will upvote your answer. But I can' accept your answer. I will wait, maybe someone has ideas where I can find analogs of the classes.

Comment: @AlexanderI. That's all right. I also hope others can give good ideas for you. I'm sorry that I don't know much about this. We can waiting for some days. If the error still with no anwser for a lang time, maybe you can think about accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the latest API document [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models?view=azure-dotnet), `RecommendedAction`, `IElasticPoolRecommendedActionsOperations`, `IElasticPoolAdvisorsOperations` are not exist now.

As you said it seems the classes were renamed or moved to other nuget package.

I didn't find anything talked about this. But from the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql?view=azure-dotnet), maybe we can find some similar inteface, such as `IElasticPoolActivitiesOperations` or `IElasticPoolOperations` . It looks like that you need to change your code and fount the new renamed class or interface by yourself.

I asked Azure Support, please wait for my update.

**Update:**

Yes, as you said in comment, Azure support replied me with the same result.

Here's Email:

Dear Leon,

Good Morning.

I got reply back from the product group developers. Kindly let me share the information.

According to the developer, below 3 modules are included in this new Library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Advisor

1. RecommendedAction from namespace Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models
2. Interface IElasticPoolRecommendedActionsOperations
3. Interface IElasticPoolAdvisorsOperations

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait. But I think Microsoft developers moved all Recommendation features to separate nuget package. It seems we need to use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Advisor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Advisor).

Comment: @AlexanderI.a Azure support still in follow up now.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderI., Azure support replied me. They confirmed that these class and interfaces are included in `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Advisor`. You can use the new library! If my answer helped, please mark it as the answer, thank you very much!